# Not able to call php function after database query result codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please find below code

```
//--Sec A--
$query = $this->db->insert('test',$insert_data);
$data['test_data'] = $query->result();

// --Sec B--- code to get inserted row

$this->addPanels($panArr,$job_Id,$test_Id);//$test_Id is result of Sec B

echo json_encode($data);//Result of Sec A
```

I am unable to understand why i am unable to get result of addPanels()

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I am inserting single row in "test" table. I want primary key ($test_Id - auto increment) of inserted row to be used in calling next function addPanels(). However i am unable to get whether that function is been called or not? Sec A works fine. Data is being inserted. However it is not performing addPanels().

Comment: Did you tried `$test_id = $this->db->insert_id();`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//--Sec A--
$query = $this->db->insert('test',$insert_data);
$data['test_data'] = $query->result();

//The insert ID number when performing database inserts.
$test_Id = $this->db->insert_id();

// --Sec B--- code to get inserted row

$this->addPanels($panArr,$job_Id,$test_Id);//$test_Id is result of Sec B

echo json_encode($data);//Result of Sec A
```